# Netty and STOMP

Tags: java, netty, stomp

How I can get **STOMP** message with **netty**?

I'm looking in **netty** example, I have a such handler:

```
public class WebSocketFrameHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<WebSocketFrame> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketFrameHandler.class);

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, 
                              WebSocketFrame frame) throws Exception {
        // ping and pong frames already handled

        if (frame instanceof TextWebSocketFrame) {
           ...
        }
     }
}
```

Does `netty` have specific tools to convert `WebSocketFrame` to `StompFrame`?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to convert WebSocketFrame to StompFrame.

Netty provide support for multiple protocols and message frames and STOMP is also one of these. If your client is sending STOMP messages then you can use 
**StompSubframeDecoder** - to decode your data(you can configure this in your initializer).
**StompSubframeEncoder** - to encode your data(you can configure this in your initializer).

And finally you can use **StompFrame** and **StompSubframe** to get the stomp type message.